# Adding OGC complaint WMS Aerial Images as Base Maps using arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I have an WMS layer which is a cross domain resource and I wanted to embed those layers as basemap in my application using JavaScript api rather than using built in ArcGIS Basemaps.

WMS Layer is complaint with OGC WMS specification & it has 5 different layers of Aerial photography images.

If it is possible, can you add these layers a basemaps in my application. Can you please piont me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a custom Layer as A BaseMap. What you can do is to initialise the Map without an BaseMap, and then add the WMS Layer.

You can include a WMS layer in your ESRI JSAPI app, by using the [esri.layers.WMSLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/wmslayer-amd.html) class.

Here is how you can do it:

```
var layer1 = new esri.layers.WMSLayerInfo({name:"1",title:"Rivers"});
var layer2 = new esri.layers.WMSLayerInfo({name:"2",title:"Cities"});
var wmsLayer = new esri.layers.WMSLayer(
"http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer",
  {resourceInfo: resourceInfo,
  visibleLayers: ["1","2"]
  }
); 
map.addLayers([wmsLayer]);
```

A sample is available here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/layers_wmsresourceinfo.html